# Building PAB error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am following https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html

I know the plutus-apps repo is newer than those docs and have downloaded it but it seems I can't build plutus-pab.

When I run

`$ nix-build -A plutus-pab`

I get:

`error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found`

I thought I had built everything but when I tried to run $ npm run start in plutus-playground-client I got this:

`sh: line 1: plutus-playground-generate-purs: command not found`

Comment: I may need to build https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab-executables but when i try $ nix-build ../default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab I get Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Was able to run $nix-build default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab from within nix-shell. Seems like it worked, but main problem still not resolved.

Comment: After a reboot, this issue seems to have resolved itself. Unfortunately I'm not sure what I did. Playground client now runs, though I cannot compile the hello world sample. On to tackling next error...

Answer (score 0):

To build needed:

$ nix-build ../default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab

<strike>in top level of plutus-apps folder.</strike>

in plutus-apps/plutus-pab-executables